# Warning Kvm is Not Available

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

I am getting this warning message while creating a new VM.

below packages are already installed.

qemu-kvm-1.5.3-160.el7.x86_64
qemu-img-1.5.3-160.el7.x86_64

[image]

**Host system Centos 7**

```
lsmod | grep kvm
kvm                   586948  0 
irqbypass              13503  1 kvm
```

**Requested output**

```
# LC_ALL=C lscpu | grep Virtualization
Virtualization:        VT-x
# grep -E --color=auto 'vmx|svm|0xc0f' /proc/cpuinfo
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm epb ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts spec_ctrl intel_stibp flush_l1d
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm epb ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts spec_ctrl intel_stibp flush_l1d
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm epb ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts spec_ctrl intel_stibp flush_l1d
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm epb ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts spec_ctrl intel_stibp flush_l1d
```

Comment: Which operating system (Linux distribution) are you running Virt Manager (with qemu) on?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `lsmod | grep kvm`? Depending on your situation, you may need to manually load some kernel modules or change your BIOS settings (if virtualization is not enabled there).

Comment: I have edited the question with your requirement

Comment: Ok It looks like a module is not loaded (either `kvm_amd` or `kvm_intel`). I would point you to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM#Checking_support_for_KVM) to check if your hardware does support virtualization and to determine what kernel module you need to load, and to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM#Loading_kernel_modules) to manually load the required modules. You may still need to enable virtualization in your BIOS configuration, but I'm not aware of a way for helping you in doing this.

Comment: To add to fran-san's tips, here's a guide for setting up KVM on CentOS 7: https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kvm-hypervisor-on-centos-7-and-rhel-7/

Comment: If `sudo modprobe kvm_intel` works without errors, you should be fine. If the module is not loaded automatically on reboot, you might want to keep following the second link in my previous comment, eventually landing to [Automatic module loading with systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Automatic_module_loading_with_systemd), and follow its advice.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_intel': Operation not supported
this is giving error.

Comment: Virtualization is probably disabled in the BIOS configuration. Try to activate. You can also use `dmesg | grep kvm` to look for additional information (e.g. it may explicitly tell you if virtualization support is disabled).